# Push data from server side to web page

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

At some point I need to send information from server side to web page.

Is it possible to send data(push data) from server side to web page?

Comment: use Ajax:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529740/mvc-and-jquery-best-pratice-for-retreiving-form-data/8154006#8154006

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you could use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) for this.

it will use websockets where available or fall back to forever frames or long polling.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) too.

> Node.js® is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily
>   building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an
>   event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and
>   efficient, perfect for data-intensive **real-time applications** that run
>   across distributed devices.